# Unable to change GPT to MBR

Tags: gpt, mbr

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda2
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present
```

Partition table scan displays only MBR as being present, but Windows won't install to the drive because it sees it as GPT. I've run gdisk a few times and tried formating, converting table filesystems, to no avail.

Comment: In your terminal, you are scanning a partition: `/dev/sda2`. The Command should be `sudo gdisk /dev/sda`. What is the output of that command.

Comment: Also, I do not recommend performing such changes unless you have backed up all the data.

Comment: @DavidFoerster It's not an exact duplicate of that question imo because of the unique situation that *partition table scan displays only MBR as being present, but Windows won't install to the drive because it sees it as GPT*.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, my mistake was running gdisk /dev/sda1 and gdisk /dev/sda2.

Answer (score 1):

***STOP!!!***

***CONVERTING YOUR DISK AS YOU'RE TRYING TO DO IS LIKELY TO LEAD TO PAIN!***

I am, however, *assuming* that you have a working Ubuntu installation on the computer. If not, or if you want to wipe it out and install nothing but Windows, you'd be better served by asking about this on a Windows forum.

The problem is that Windows ties its partition table type to its boot mode: Windows installs in EFI mode only to GUID Partition Table (GPT) disks, and in BIOS mode only to Master Boot Record (MBR) disks. Ubuntu *prefers* to install in this way, too, but it's sometimes possible to install and boot in BIOS mode from a GPT disk or, with a bit more hoop-jumping, in EFI mode from an MBR disk. In any event, the fact that you've got a GPT disk means that your Ubuntu is *probably* booting in EFI mode. Thus, the proper solution is to install Windows in that mode, too. This requires modifying how you boot the Windows installer.

This is *often* (but not always) simply a matter of selecting the correct option in the computer's built-in boot manager. Typically, you'll see two options for the boot medium, one of which includes the string "UEFI" and the other of which does not. Select the option that *does* include "UEFI" in its description to boot in EFI mode. This should clear the problem. You may also want or need to disable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM). This is an EFI feature that enables it to boot BIOS-mode boot loaders. If you're booting in EFI mode, the CSM is nothing but trouble, as described in [my page on the subject.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

If you don't see an option to boot your installation disk in EFI mode, it's conceivable that your disk is improperly prepared. Some tools to turn `.iso` images into bootable USB drives omit the EFI boot loader. Also, if this is Windows 7 you're trying to boot in this way, there can be some extra hurdles. Various Web pages, [like this one,](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2011/05/31/installing-windows-7-on-uefi-based-computer/) cover this topic.

I recommend that you read my page on the CSM (referenced earlier). It's written mainly for people who want to install Linux second, but the general principles apply to your situation. The section near the end on preparing media may be of interest, too.

You may have noticed that I referred to the possibility of installing Ubuntu in BIOS mode to a GPT disk. If you've got such a configuration, you'll need to change something -- either the Ubuntu boot mode or the partition table. You can identify your Ubuntu boot mode by looking for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi` in Ubuntu. If this directory is present, you've booted in EFI mode; if it's absent, you've almost certainly booted in BIOS mode.

If I'm right that Ubuntu is booting in EFI mode, and if you install Windows next, then the computer is almost certain to boot straight to Windows when you're done. There are several ways to restore a dual-boot configuration after that. The least painful is likely to be:

1. Boot to Windows.
2. Download and install the [EasyUEFI utility.](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html)
3. Launch EasyUEFI.
4. In the EasyUEFI window, you'll see a list of boot options, one of which is called "ubuntu." Move it to the top of the list.
5. Reboot. GRUB should appear and launch Ubuntu. (You might or might not actually see a GRUB menu.)
6. Open a Terminal window.
7. Type `sudo update-grub` in the Terminal Window.

At this point, when you reboot you should see GRUB, and it should enable you to boot either Ubuntu or Windows.

If you need more help, please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

By the way, Aditya is correct; you're launching `gdisk` on a partition, not on the whole disk. You should use `gdisk` only on whole-disk devices.